# Jythonc : How to use?

Tags: java, jython

I am new to jython. Here is my failed attempt to use javac to complie my python script into class file.

```
    rohit@rohit-laptop:~/backyard$ echo "print 'hi'" > test.py
    rohit@rohit-laptop:~/backyard$ jython test.py 
    hi
    rohit@rohit-laptop:~/backyard$ jythonc test.py 
    Warning: jythonc is unmaintained and will not be included in Jython-2.3.  See http://jython.org/Project/jythonc.html for alternatives to jythonc.  Add '-i' to your invocation of jythonc to turn off this warning
    processing test

    Required packages:

    Creating adapters:

    Creating .java files:
      test module

    Compiling .java to .class...
    Compiling with args: ['/usr/bin/javac', '-classpath', '/usr/share/java/jython.jar:/usr/share/java/servlet-api-2.4.jar:/usr/share/java/libreadline-java.jar:./jpywork::/usr/share/jython/Tools/jythonc:/usr/share/jython/Lib:/usr/lib/site-python:__classpath__', './jpywork/test.java']
    0  
    rohit@rohit-laptop:~/backyard$ 
    rohit@rohit-laptop:~/backyard$ cd jpywork/
    rohit@rohit-laptop:~/backyard/jpywork$ ls
    test.class  test.java  test$_PyInner.class
    rohit@rohit-laptop:~/backyard/jpywork$ java test 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/core/PyObject
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.python.core.PyObject
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    Could not find the main class: test. Program will exit.
    rohit@rohit-laptop:~/backyard/jpywork$
```

Please suggest the correct way.

Comment: I would recommend, after reading the jythonc webpages, to abandon jythonc (it seems to be what they recommend)

Comment: If you have `jythonc`, then you must be running Jython 2.2. We're at 2.5.1 and Jython has greatly improved over the last few releases.

Comment: yeah.. I have chosen to abandon it.

Answer (score 0):

Jython will automatically compile it into .class file on first execution, however in case you want to compile it, you can use standard library, find py_compile.py or compileall.py on Jython lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ java test # is not the exact command to execute the class file
```

this class file requires `jython.jar` file to execute you have to give the `jython.jar` path at the run time.

```
#java -cp /home/litindia/jython-2.0.1/jython.jar:. test
```

`-cp` is compulsory `/home/litindia/jython-2.0.1/jython.jar` is my path where is `jython.jar` is present in my system, your path may be different. so please give the appropriate path.

And after the path `:.` is compulsory. Then file name is required.